# Xcode 7: No launchImage on simulator for iOS 9

Tags: iphone, swift2, ios9, xcode7, launchimage

I've updated Xcode to Xcode 7. Then my Swift project to Swift 2. At last I removed removed all warnings.

Everything was fine on previous version of Xcode. On Xcode 7, LaunchImage does not display on simulator for iOS 9 but display for iOS 8.

All places are filled on assets: remember it work well on iOS8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unset LaunchImage, save, then reset LaunchImage.

If the issue is still there, you can try recreate your xcodeproj.

Comment: Try it: does not change anything.

Comment: Ok, it works now. Cleaning derived data + Create a new LaunchImage assets and then back to previous. Thanks!